# Contradiction in an Alternative Definition of an Open Set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> A set $G$ in $\mathbb R^p$ is said to be open in $\mathbb R^p$ if , $\forall x \in G$, $\exists r \in \mathbb R^+$ such that every point $y$ in $\mathbb R^p$ satisfying $|x-y|<r$ also belongs to the set $G$.

Lets consider the open interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$. Lets take $x=0.5$. Now,  lets take a positive quantity $r=600$

Then $|0.5-500|=499.5<600$ and the point $x=500$ clearly $ \in \mathbb R$ **But** $x=500 \notin (0,1)$ which means then, by the above definition, $(0,1) $ must not be an open set , which we know is not true.

Where must I be making a mistake?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You took a too large $r$. Try $r = 0.3$ for example.

Comment: It doesn't hold for all $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$, but there exists such an $r$. This doesn't mean you can just pick an arbitrary $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence "$~~\forall~ x \in G, ~~\exists~r \in \mathbb R^+$ such that " translates to;

For every $x$ in $G$ there exists a positive quantity $r$ such that ...

Notice that all we need is one quantity $r$ for which the rest of the sentence is true. And this $r$ corresponds to a particular $x$ in $G$. And every $x$ in $G$ must have a corresponding $r$.

We cannot stipulate what $r$ is arbitrarily which you have done. All the statement says is that there is such an $r$ for every $x \in G$.

As for your example for every $x \in (0,1)$ there is $r = \min \{ |x - 1|, |x - 0| \}$ so that if  $ y $ conforms to $ |x - y| \lt r$, then $y$ too is in $(0,1)$. Note the $r$ defined here **exists** for every point in the unit open interval.

Comment: Hey, one question please .. If we consider the set $[0,1]$. Can't we define an $r$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ in a similar fashion you did above?

Comment: okay i got it !

Comment: Sorry was off for a bit. I'm guessing you figured out it wouldn't work for $0$ and $1$.